Formgroup showing values of another formgroup in formarray
I am using angular reactive forms module to bind to different formgroups in a formarray called "days". I have them in a material drag and drop for loop in the template. When I click a button on the for loop divs, it should show details about the day in a bootstrap modal. When I click one day it shows properly. However, when I click another day it shows the data from the previous day I clicked.
I have set up the template properly with all the necessary properties, including: FormGroup, formarrayname, formGroupName, and formcontrolname. The html for the day modal looks like this
      <form class="modal-body" [formGroup]="WorkoutForm">
          <div class="day-form" formArrayName="days">
            <div *ngIf="this.selectedFitnessDayIndex >= 0" class="specific-day-form"
              [formGroupName]="selectedFitnessDayIndex">
              <div *ngIf="!editWorkoutToggled">
              <div class="workoutheaderbuttons">
                <button  style="margin-right: 1em;" *ngIf="!this.requestProposal"
                  (click)="saveFitnessDayLoadout(selectedFitnessDayIndex)" class="savedaybutton btn btn-secondary"
                  type="button" name="button">Save Day <br> loadout</button>
                <button *ngIf="!this.requestProposal" (click)="toggleLoadFitnessDay(selectedFitnessDayIndex)"
                  class="loaddaybutton btn btn-secondary" type="button" name="button">Load day <br>loadout</button>
              </div>
              <h5 [ngClass]="{'saveDayFaulty': this.WorkoutForm.value.days[selectedFitnessDayIndex].saveDayMessage !== 'Succesfully saved this fitness day as a loadout', 'saveDaySuccesful': this.WorkoutForm.value.days[selectedFitnessDayIndex].saveDayMessage == 'Succesfully saved this fitness day as a loadout'}" style="padding-top: .6em;width: 80%;text-align: center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">{{this.WorkoutForm.value.days[selectedFitnessDayIndex].saveDayMessage}}</h5>
              <p *ngIf="this.WorkoutForm.value.days[selectedFitnessDayIndex].loadDayToggled && this.savedFitnessDays.length == 0">You have no saved fitness day loadouts</p>
                <div *ngIf="this.WorkoutForm.value.days[selectedFitnessDayIndex].loadDayToggled && this.savedFitnessDays.length > 0" class="loaddayparent">
                  <p>Select Fitness Day to Load: *</p>
                  <div class="dayoptions">
                    <div *ngFor="let option of this.savedFitnessDays;let optionIndex=index;" class="dayOption">
                      <h5 (click)="selectFitnessDayLoadout(option._id, selectedFitnessDayIndex)">{{option.name}}</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                  <label for="">Change Day Name: </label>
                  <p>selected day index: {{selectedFitnessDayIndex}}</p>
                 <h3>Day value : {{ WorkoutForm.days[selectedFitnessDayIndex].dayName}}</h3> 
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="dayName">
                  <label for="">Rest Days after This Day: </label>
                  <input [readonly]="this.requestProposal" class="form-control" formControlName="restdaysAfter" type="number"
                    name="" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
  
        </form> 

I am using a manually set index variable to store the index that is used in the formGroupName. The component.ts code that is used to set that variable looks like this:
openDayModal(dayIndex: number){
    this.selectedFitnessDay = this.getDays().value.at(dayIndex);
    this.selectedFitnessDayIndex = dayIndex;
    console.log('this day:', this.getDays().at(dayIndex).value);
    console.log("SELECTED INDEX", this.selectedFitnessDayIndex);
  }

and that openDayModal() function is being called in the template here:
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          @for (day of getDays().controls; track day; let dayIndex = $index;) {
            <div class="example-box" cdkDrag>
              <div class="example-custom-placeholder" *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>
              
              <p>{{day.value.dayName}}</p>
              <p (click)="openDayModal(dayIndex)"  data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#fitnessDayModal" class="edit-day">Edit <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></p>
              
            </div>
          }
        </div>


It's looks like there're a "bug" when you change the selectedFitnessDayIndex and it's not make really a binding in a formGroupName
   [formGroupName]="selectedFitnessDayIndex"

As you store in the variable selectedFitnessDay the formGroup in your code
  openDayModal(dayIndex: number){
    this.selectedFitnessDay = this.getDays().value.at(dayIndex);
    this.selectedFitnessDayIndex = dayIndex as FormGroup; //<--this line
  }

You can use directly
  //replace in your model  
  <form class="modal-body" [formGroup]="WorkoutForm">
      <div class="day-form" formArrayName="days">
        <div *ngIf="this.selectedFitnessDayIndex >= 0" class="specific-day-form"
          [formGroupName]="selectedFitnessDayIndex">
            ...this code is the same..
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>

  //by
  <form *ngIf="selectedFitnessDay " [formGroup]="selectedFitnessDay">
         ...this code is the same..
  </form>

a little stackblitz
